# Adding new layers to a trained YOLOV3 model

Tags: yolo

I followed tutorial from machinelearningmastery to build a YOLOV3 model("https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-object-detection-with-yolov3-in-keras/")

YOLO predicts output from three levels . This is the layer being outputted after the last layer 
    model = Model(input_image, [yolo_82, yolo_94, yolo_106]
    return model

Now i want to flatten this layer, add few fully connected layers and add a sigmoid layer on top of it

But when i flatten (flat1 = Flatten()(model.outputs)), i get this error

And got this error “Layer flatten_1 expects 1 inputs, but it received 3 input tensors. I understand why this error is displayed, as model.outputs is actually the outputs from three layers 82, 94 and 106

So what i am thinking is should i get outputs from each layer separately and flatten them separately, and then do a np.stack of them, and then again flatten it

```
out1= model.outputs[0]
out2 = model.outputs[1]
out3 = model.outputs[2]

stacked_outputs = np.stack((out1,out2,out3))

flat1 = Flatten(stacked_outputs)
```

I am hoping to implement a binary classification on top of the yolov3 model built in the website machine learning mastery. If someone can guide me to add these layers, it will be very helpful

I am new to learning deep learning, so if my question or my way of asking is too dumb, pls forgive